# Grok strange issue

Tags: elasticsearch, grok

we're using pipeline in Elasticsearch to simulate a grok filter.
We encounter the following strange behaviour.

if the timestamp field is at the start of the message the grok filter doesn't work.

```
## GROK NOT WORK
    POST /_ingest/pipeline/_simulate
    {
      "pipeline": {
        "processors": [
          {
            "grok": {
              "field": "message",
              "patterns": ["""%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:@timestamp} %{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:@timestamp}"""]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
        "docs": [
        {
          "_source": {
            "message": "2019-09-29T00:39:02.91ZZ 55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043  "
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

We've the following error:

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "error" : {
        "root_cause" : [
          {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "Provided Grok expressions do not match field value: [2019-09-29T00:39:02.91ZZ 55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043  ]"
          }
        ],
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Provided Grok expressions do not match field value: [2019-09-29T00:39:02.91ZZ 55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043  ]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In this format, the timestamp at the end of the message, the grok filter works fine.

```
    ## GROK WORKS FINE
    POST /_ingest/pipeline/_simulate
    {
      "pipeline": {
        "processors": [
          {
            "grok": {
              "field": "message",
              "patterns": ["""%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:@timestamp}"""]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
        "docs": [
        {
          "_source": {
            "message": "55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043 2019-09-29T00:39:02.91ZZ"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I find it weird that your timestamp has two `ZZ` characters at the end... doesn't seem ISO8601-compatible

Answer (score 0):

From your first example i see 2 problems with your GROK expression:

1. At the end of the grok expression you have a second timestamp (probably copy paste issue?)
2. the second issue is the timezone `ZZ` at the end of your timestamp. if you want to disregard it you can add %{NOTSPACE} right after your timestamp to disregard this extra timezone chars.

You can try the following grok:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{NOTSPACE} %{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}
```

That was tested in GROK debugger and is working for me.
I suggest you to work closely with GROK debugger (in Kibana->Dev Tools->Grok Debugger) or you can find some online grok debugger.

Lastly, I suggest you add `:int` or `:float` after using "NUMBER" format like this `%{NUMBER:duration:float}` in order to be able to use greater/smaller filters in ES.

Answer (score 0):

Can use https://regex101.com/r/eRAJg3/1 to match the date. LMK if that helps.

You could then use Oniguruma syntax in your grok expression:

```
(?<ts>([\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}T[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}\.[\d]{2}Z{2}))
```

For reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns

You should also remove the second instance of a timestamp from your first expression, as eladyanai pointed out.

For completeness, I'll provide the full expression:

```
(?<ts>([\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}T[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}\.[\d]{2}Z{2})) %{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}%{SPACE}
```

Answer (score -1):

Their is "ZZ" after time which is not ISO compatible.

You can add .* -->  "0 or more of any character"

%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:@timestamp}.*

and * after last timestamp pattern to make it optional

```
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "grok": {
          "field": "message",
          "patterns": [
            "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:@timestamp}.* %{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:@timestamp}*"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "message": "2019-09-29T00:39:02.91ZZ 55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043  "
      }
    }
  ]
```

Result:

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "duration" : "0.043",
          "request" : "/index.html",
          "@timestamp" : "2019-09-29T00:39:02.91Z",
          "method" : "GET",
          "bytes" : "15824",
          "client" : "55.3.244.1",
          "message" : "2019-09-29T00:39:02.91ZZ 55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043  "
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2020-04-18T10:43:39.8725873Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your suggested solution is not working. You have disregarded the fact he has a second timestamp at the end of the GROK pattern which is causing it to fail. also this is a bad practice to mix GROK expression with regular expression when it is possible to avoid it.